# Change size of video element based on how many there are

Tags: javascript

I have div container in which I'm putting generated *video* tags via `JS` based on how many users there are. How can I make them change size based on how many there are, like if there is only one video tag make it 100% of a parent div and if 3 let first be 80% and rest be 10%.

```html
<div class="video-grid">

</div>
```

this is my function that adds new video elements to the video grid

```js
function add(video,stream){
 video.srcObject = stream
 video.addEventListener('loadmetadata', () =>{
   video.play()
 })
 videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing but I'm going to bet you are looking for `video.style.width` that sets the CSS, (note: properties must be on camelCase), so `video.style.width = users.length === 1 ? "100%" : /* your logic here */ 33.333%;`

Comment: i'm looking for something like if video tags numer is 2 make them 50% else make them 33% but i don't know how to du such if statment in js

Comment: This `Array.from(videoTags).map((video, index) => { video.style.width = ( 100 / index ).toFixed(2)+"%";  })` ?

Comment: or simply this `video.style.width = videoTags.length > 3 ? "33%" : (100 / videoTags.length).toFixed(2)+"%";` ?